# JS select child of this with specific class

Tags: javascript

I am writing a GreaseMonkey script that goes through a page with various elements and each element has text and a button. It uses `document.getElementsByClassName` to find the parent elements, and it has a for loop to do something to each parent element. In this loop, I need to select a child node with a specific class and find its text value (`innerHTML`). I can't figure out how to select the child with a specific class of this element.

Comment: No, the child element which I'm selecting only has a class.

Comment: Why not use jQuery, things can be easy: var value = $('.parentClass .childClass').html();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to grab the currently iterated element and use `querySelector()`

For example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
   var child = elements[i].querySelector('.class_of_desired_element');

   //do stuff with child
}
```

Note the dot before the class name in `querySelector` as it works similar to jQuery.

Comment: Note that using querySelector() instead of querySelectorAll() will only select the first element that matches, rather than all matches.

Answer (score 2):

Try `querySelectorAll()`, which you can use to find elements within the current element.

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parentClass'),
parent[0].querySelectorAll('.childClass');
```

Depending on exactly what you are looking to do, you could also skip selecting the parent, if you don't explicitly need a reference to it.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.parentClass .childClass');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var yourelement = document.getElementsByClass("");
var i = yourelement.nextSibling;
var e = i.nextSibling;
```

and keep getting the `nextSibling` of the element till you get it.

However, like @teddy said in the comments, I would suggest you use jQuery. It has a MUCH easier way to do it:

```
 var value = $('.parentClass .childClass').html();
```